# Export GMail subject by label to flat file

Tags: gmail, export

I would like to extract the subject of all 300 emails in one "folder" (label) to a file

Any suggestions?

I do NOT have outlook - I do have the emails in Thunderbird on OSX though

Thanks

Comment: you might start here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/417/export-gmail-messages-to-text-or-html-files

Comment: No luck so far there. Either the program was not free or did not work or both

Comment: cannot connect to imap.gmail.com - first program on the page